# Run a command line with custom environment

Tags: ruby, environment, popen

In Ruby, I want to be able to:

1. run a command line (via shell)
2. capture both stdout and stderr (preferably as single stream) without using `>2&1` (which fails for some commands here)
3. run with additional enviornment variables (without modifying the environment of the ruby program itself)

I learned that `Open3` allows me to do 1 and 2.

```
              cmd = 'a_prog --arg ... --arg2 ...'
              Open3.popen3("#{cmd}") { |i,o,e|
                output = o.read()
                error = e.read()
                # FIXME: don't want to *separate out* stderr like this
                repr = "$ #{cmd}\n#{output}"
              }
```

I also learned that [popen](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M000880) allows you to pass an environment but *not* when specifying the commandline.

How do I write code that does all the three?

...

Put differently, what is the Ruby equivalent of the following Python code?

```
>>> import os, subprocess
>>> env = os.environ.copy()
>>> env['MYVAR'] = 'a_value'
>>> subprocess.check_output('ls -l /notexist', env=env, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
```

Comment: that `FIXME` is now a separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917993

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`Open.popen3` optionally accepts a hash as the first argument (in which case your command would be the second argument:

```
cmd = 'a_prog --arg ... --arg2 ...'
Open3.popen3({"MYVAR" => "a_value"}, "#{cmd}") { |i,o,e|
  output = o.read()
  error = e.read()
  # FIXME: don't want to *separate out* stderr like this
  repr = "$ #{cmd}\n#{output}"
}
```

`Open` uses `Process.spawn` to start the command, so you can look at the [documentation for Process.spawn](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9/classes/Process.html#M002230) to see all of it's options.

Comment: That gives an error: `open3.rb:67:in 'exec': can't convert Hash into String (TypeError)`. See https://gist.github.com/959977

Comment: Actually, that was Ruby 1.8, but it works on Ruby 1.9. Let me try it in the actual code ... (I must have read 1.8's doc)

Comment: Yes, it's 1.9-specific. It looks like 1.8 used a much smaller and more limited set of features in Open3.