# Merge stdout and stderr in Popen

Tags: ruby, stdout, popen, stderr

In Ruby's popen/spawn, how do I merge both STDOUT and STDERR as a single stream wihthout resorting to using `>2&1`?

In Python, this would be:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output('my_prog args', stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
```

Note the `stderr` argument.

[I use Open3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917821/run-a-command-line-with-custom-environment) - as I don't want *just* stdout - but it already separates them into two streams.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the code from your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917821/run-a-command-line-with-custom-environment/5917927#5917927), here you go:

```
cmd = 'a_prog --arg ... --arg2 ...'
Open3.popen2({"MYVAR" => "a_value"}, "#{cmd}", {:err => [:child, :out]}) { |i,o|
  # This output should include stderr as well
  output = o.read()
  repr = "$ #{cmd}\n#{output}"
}
```

A couple changes:

1. The third parameter to `popen2` will redirect stderr to stdoutl. Note that it needs to be the spawned process's stdout, not the system-wide stdout, so you need to specify `:child`'s `:out`
2. You need to use `.popen2` instead of `.popen3` as it seems the redirection is ignored if you include the 3rd `e` option for stderr
3. Because you're using `.popen2`, you only pass `|i,o|` to the block:

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but take a look at `Open3.popen2e` -  [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen2e).

This behaves exactly as `popen3`, but merges `stderr` `stdout` as the second argument to the block.

So you can simply do

```
cmd = 'a_prog --arg ... --arg2 ...'
Open3.popen2e(cmd) { |input,output|
 # Process as desired, with output containing stdout and stderr
}
```