# Travis CI: Failing because executing a local bash executable isn't found, but it's definitely here

Tags: ruby, executable, executable-jar, execution, travis-ci

My gem uses a local copy of Tidy HTML Validator. It's available in `lib/tidy/tidy`. My tests run perfectly locally, but on Travis CI, I'm getting the error that Tidy can't be found.

```
Errno::ENOENT:
No such file or directory - tidy
```

The code looks like this:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = Open3.popen3('tidy -quiet')
```

Is there a restriction or something that prevents executing a local executable? I also call a local copy of the Jigsaw CSS Validator which is a Java `jar` file and is executed like this:

```
`java -jar css-validator.jar --output=soap12 file:#{uri}`
```

This works perfectly on Travis CI. Could there be a problem with `Open3`?

Here's the link to the GitHub repo: https://github.com/jmuheim/headhunter
Here's the link to the failing Travis CI build: https://travis-ci.org/jmuheim/headhunter

**Update**

I have rewritten the code that executes the external `java` executable to also use `Open3`, and it's working. So the problem has to do with `tidy`.

For further debugging I have renamed `tidy` into `tidy2` (to make sure that really the wanted executable is called), and I added a manual `File.exist? 'tidy'` before calling it, so this would raise an error if it couldn't be found.

```
  Dir.chdir(VALIDATOR_DIR) do
    raise "Could not find tidy in #{Dir.pwd}" unless File.exists? EXECUTABLE

    # Docs for Tidy: http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html
    stdin, stdout, stderr = Open3.popen3("#{EXECUTABLE} -quiet")
    # ...
  end
```

The file is definitely found, but executing it still results in this error.

```
 1) Headhunter::HtmlValidator#validate returns a local response when calling the validator succeeds
 Failure/Error: subject.validate('invalid.html', read_file('html_validator/invalid.html'))
 Errno::ENOENT:
   No such file or directory - tidy2
 # ./lib/headhunter/html_validator.rb:20:in `block in validate'
 # ./lib/headhunter/html_validator.rb:16:in `chdir'
 # ./lib/headhunter/html_validator.rb:16:in `validate'
 # ./spec/lib/headhunter/html_validator_spec.rb:9:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/lib/headhunter/html_validator_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

So the only thing I can guess now is that be there is a permissions problem? Is there a way to set permissions to local executables with Travis CI?

I also tried putting `tidy` into `bin` like somebody suggested in the comments, but this didn't seem to change a thing, too.

Comment: you probably need to specify the absolute path to the executable `Open3.popen3('lib/tidy/tidy -quiet')`

Comment: put your `tidy` bin, into `bin/` folder of your gem.

Comment: I have added more infos about the issue. Maybe a permissions problem?

Answer (score 1):

A couple things:

Typically the environment is different than your current environment when spawning programs so you have to check what the environment is. This is the case in `cron`, `monit`, and for some ruby method calls.

In your case, for Open, it uses `Process.spawn` so you're not guaranteed to be in your own directory. `Open.popen3` takes a `:chdir` option, so set that to your `Dir.pwd` and see what happens.

You can also try just using absolute paths.

**Sources**

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5917927/463225

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Process.html#method-c-spawn

Comment: This is very interesting. While I'm quite sure that inz's answer is the correct one, this one has some very useful hints, too. I will get back to both of you as soon as I tried out your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `tidy2` executable is a [Mach-O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O) binary for OS X, but the Travis worker runs Linux. Try to include a suitable ELF binary from http://tidy.sourceforge.net/#binaries.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds reasonable. I will take a look at it soon.